# How to use url with #

Tags: html

I have a lot of images with a url like this one:

```
KM_72#050#500.svg
```

When I will open the image in my Laravel application, the server response is 404.

If I change the file name to `KM_72-050-500.svg` it works. It means, that the path is ok.

The images are from a customer. So, I like to use themes with the original name.

Is there a possibility to change the url to cover the `#`?

Comment: Try replacing # with %23 which is url encoded text for #

Comment: If you need to search for others codes you can use this source https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP

Comment: You could use this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/he

Answer (score 0):

As @RABI said, to encode reserved characters (such as #) into url content, you should use the correct url encoding.

The following page contains an ASCII url encoding table: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP

Notice that if you want to programmatically encode strings you can use in js the function encodeURIComponent(string).

Answer (score 0):

There are special characters which are reserved and not to be used as a part of a url.

The characters which **may** be used in a url are:

> ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-._~:/?#[]@!$&'()*+,;=

Note it does not say where in the url they are to be used. Any other character needs to be encoded with the percent-encoding (`%hh`). Each part of the URI has further restrictions about what characters need to be represented by an percent-encoded word.

Note that some of these characters for example, the hash symbol, have specific meanings, and if you want to avoid these "meanings" then you must use the percent-encoding. The way to use this programatically is by using the built-in function:

```js
const my_hash_symbol = encodeURIComponent("#");
console.log(my_hash_symbol); // => %23

// Later, decode it if you wish
const original_symbol = decodeURIComponent("%23");
console.log(original_symbol); // => #
```

**Edit**: The "meaning" of the hash-symbol ("#") results in the browser looking for a file named `KM_72` instead of the full `KM_72#050#500.svg`, which of course does not exist.

The '#' character falls into the category of "delims":

> `delims      = "<" | ">" | "#" | "%" | <">`

which does not cause a crash or error (directly), but does change the behaviour of the browser's file searching mechanism which results in a non-direct 404 error.